# Database logic advice needed for saving and displaying pages with sub-pages in Laravel / PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, logic, eloquent

This is the first app I am building (in Laravel) thats not a "to do" list from a tutorial and I’m looking for the best way to implement some database logic.

I am building an app where users can create pages and sub pages. However, there are different types of page templates, such as:

- Audio: (for embedding Soundcloud)
- Video: (for embedding YouTube)

Each template can be used several times with a custom name and slug, which means you can have multiple audio templates with titles such as "tracks" or "mixes".

The front-end URL structure will go like:

website.com/username/mixes/ - Display a list of mixes

website.com/username/mixes/name-of-mix - Go directly to each mix

In the admin area the user will follow a path of

1. Add new page (simple link)
2. Choose a template (such as audio or video)
3. Selects audio template and names it Mixes (front-end
   website.com/username/mixes)
4. Returns to a newly created (but empty) Mixes page
5. User clicks on "Add new audio item"
6. Creates a new audio item called "Name of mix"
7. This force the previous first part of the slug to be /mixes/ and
   then adds "name-of-mix" at the end.
8. The user can repeat this multiple times for the Mixes page.

All of the above I can implement (within the controllers in Laravel).

The problem I am having is what is the best/cleanest way to implement this in the database?

Do I...

OPTION ONE - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

Save every page and sub page in the pages model and reference templates (if a sub-page) from it, such as:

Landing page (website.com/username/mixes)

new Page:

```
- id: 1
- user_id: 1
- format: audio
- format_id: null
- template: audio_landing
- title: Mixes
- slug: mixes
```

Single page (website.com/username/mixes/name-of-mix)

When this is saved it will create a Page and also create a separate Audio item

new Audio:

```
- id: 6
- user_id: 1
- title: Name of mix
- embed_code: 7654365
```

new Page:

```
- id: 2
- user_id: 1
- format: audio
- format_id: 6
- template: audio_single
- title: null (title is on the audio model)
- slug: mixes/name-of-mix
```

Then in my views I would call website.com/`{username}`/`{slug}`

The query would only scan through the User model (for the username), then the Pages model, stop when its found the correct slug then references the associated Audio model and creates a view for that page. This (I think) would be a faster and a less intensive (on MySQL) way of grabbing the page info.

Am I correct in thinking, from the Pages model, I can use "`format: audio`" to search the Audio model and the “`format_id: 6`" to match it to the model "`id: 6`”

OPTION TWO - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

Save pages in Pages then save sub-pages in the Audio model

Landing page (website.com/username/mixes)

new Page:

```
- id: 1
- user_id: 1
- template: audio_landing
- title: Mixes
- slug: mixes
```

Single page (website.com/username/mixes/name-of-mix)

This will save directly in the Audio model

new Audio:

```
- id: 6
- user_id: 1
- template: audio_single
- title: Name of mix
- embed_code: 7654365 
- slug: mixes/name-of-mix
```

Then in my views I would call website.com/`{username}`/`{slug}`

The downside (I think) is the query would have to search through the Pages, Audio, Video, Gigs, Blog, Events, Etc models before it found the correct slug. This, I presume, would be very intensive on the database each time as page request is loaded?

Sorry to run on a bit, any advice would be very welcome.

Jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered having a table just for slugs, thus giving the routing logic of your app a single place to look to determine what it has to display?

The slugs table would, of course, need a "type" field that identifies the type of thing that it points to.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense, I'll give that a try :)